# Why the sql query to update password in not running in a php script of a webpage?

Tags: php, backend, change-password

I am creating a website which have two database table of client and freelancer. Now i have to integrate everything, like profile credentials, password, images etc.

initially the application have two different files(in two different folders) that handels. The change in passwords and other profile credentials such as name, username and email of freelancer and client.
So to integrate everything into single file, i am executing all the sql queries of freelancer table in the client one. All the profile credentials get updated successfully, but not the password. I dont understand why?

#### This is Client/profile.php file

```php
$client = new Client();
$freelancer = new Freelancer();

//Check if Client is logged in
if (!$client->isLoggedIn() && !$freelancer->isLoggedIn()) { 
    Redirect::to('../index.php');
}

//Get Instructor's Data
$query = DB::getInstance()->get("client", "*", ["clientid" => $client->data()->clientid]);
if ($query->count()) {
    foreach ($query->results() as $row) {
        $nid = $row->id;
        $name = $row->name; 
        $username = $row->username;
        $email = $row->email;
        $bgimage = $row->bgimage;
        $phone = $row->phone;
    }
}

//Edit Profile Data
if (isset($_POST['profile'])) {
    if (Input::exists()) {
        if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

            $errorHandler = new ErrorHandler;

            $validator = new Validator($errorHandler);

            $validation = $validator->check($_POST, [
                'username' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'maxlength' => 20,
                    'minlength' => 2
                ],
                'name' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'maxlength' => 100,
                    'minlength' => 2
                ],
                'email' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'maxlength' => 255,
                    'email' => true,
                ],
                'phone' => [
                    'required' => false,
                    'maxlength' => 10,
                    'minlength' => 10
                ]
            ]);

            if (!$validation->fails()) {


                $client->update([
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'phone' => Input::get('phone')
                ], [
                    'clientid' => $client->data()->clientid
                ]);

                if (count($client) > 0) {
                    $noError = true;
                } 
                else {
                    $hasError = true;
                }

                $freelancer->update([
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'phone' => Input::get('phone')
                ], [
                    'freelancerid' => $freelancer->data()->freelancerid
                ]);

                if (count($freelancer) > 0) {
                    $noError = true;
                } else {
                    $hasError = true;
                }
            } 
            else {
                $error = '';
                foreach ($validation->errors()->all() as $err) {
                    $str = implode(" ", $err);
                    $error .= '
               <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Error!</strong> ' . $str . '
               </div>
               ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*Edit Password Data*/
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (Input::exists()) {
        if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

            $errorHandler = new ErrorHandler;

            $validator = new Validator($errorHandler);

            $validation = $validator->check($_POST, [
                'password_current' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'maxlength' => 300
                ],
                'password_new' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'minlength' => 6
                ],
                'password_new_again' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'match' => 'password_new'
                ]
            ]);

            if (!$validation->fails()) { //working fine

                if ( (Hash::make(Input::get('password_current'), $client->data()->salt) !== $client->data()->password) && (Hash::make(Input::get('password_current'), $freelancer->data()->salt) !== $freelancer->data()->password) ){
                    $hasError = true; 
                } 
                else {
                    $salt = Hash::salt(32);
                    
                    $changed_password = Hash::make(Input::get('password_new'), $salt);
                    
                     $client->update([
                        'password' => $changed_password, 
                        'salt' => $salt
                     ], [
                        'clientid' => $client->data()->clientid
                     ]);
                    $noError = true;
                }

                if (!$validation->fails()) { //not working
    
                    if (Hash::make(Input::get('password_current'), $freelancer->data()->salt) !== $freelancer->data()->password) {
                        $hasError = true;
                    } 
                    else {
                          $salt = Hash::salt(32);
                          $freelancer->update([
                            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password_new'), $salt),
                            'salt' => $salt
                              ],[
                            'freelancerid' => $freelancer->data()->freelancerid
                              ]);
                          $noError = true;
                }
            }
            
            else {
                $error = '';
                foreach ($validation->errors()->all() as $err) {
                    $str = implode(" ", $err);
                    $error .= '
               <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Error!</strong> ' . $str . '
               </div>
               ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### This is Freelancer/profile.php file code to change password

```php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    if (Input::exists()) {
        if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
 
            $errorHandler = new ErrorHandler;
    
            $validator = new Validator($errorHandler);
    
            $validation = $validator->check($_POST, [
                'password_current' => [
                'required' => true,
                'maxlength' => 300
                ],
                'password_new' => [
                'required' => true,
                'minlength' => 6
                ],
                'password_new_again' => [
                'required' => true,
                'match' => 'password_new'
                ]
            ]);
         
            if (!$validation->fails()) {
    
                if (Hash::make(Input::get('password_current'), $freelancer->data()->salt) !== $freelancer->data()->password) {
                    $hasError = true;
                } 
                else {
                    $salt = Hash::salt(32);
                    $freelancer->update([
                        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password_new'), $salt),
                        'salt' => $salt
                        ],[
                        'freelancerid' => $freelancer->data()->freelancerid
                        ]);
                    $noError = true;
                }
      
            } 
            else {
                $error = '';
                foreach ($validation->errors()->all() as $err) {
                    $str = implode(" ",$err);
                    $error .= '
                        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                        <strong>Error!</strong> '.$str.'
                        </div>
                    ';
            }
        }   
        }
}
}
```

My question is if the query to change username, email and phone number is working fine, why the password change for freelancer is not working?

Comment: try to display (possibly with a die($var); to prevent the new page) what you insert. $ ppp = Hash :: make (Input :: get ('password_new'), $ salt); die ($ ppp) and see if $ ppp contains the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash function algorithm can give two encrypted strings for a same inputed string so when i am calling the function two times for the client and the freelancer, two different strings and getting stored in the data base.